# How to do unit testing on a java project which having 95% dependency.?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am working on a java based project. which having so many dependency. Each process interact with server as it is requirement. Can we use any unit testing? If yes with example & if no with reason.

Comment: I can not think of any java source code that can not be unit tested. There are mocking frameworks available like Mockito, PowerMock which let you mock pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use testing in this scenario.
You'll have to use some form of mocking (Moq framework) to mock server resources.

One of the important steps would be using Dependency Injection. You'll need to do a lot of code refactoring in order to use Moq framework. for e.g.

```
class WeatherReportDisplay
{
    WeatherServerSomeWhereInIowa objserver = new WeatherServerSomeWhereInIowa();

    void PrintWeatherReport()
    {
        foreach (var item in objserver.Weather.Items)
        {
            Println(item.City + " " + item.temprature);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to change code of this form to

```
class WeatherReportDisplay
{
    IWeatherServer objserver;

    // Constructor Injection
    WeatherReportDisplay(IWeatherServer server)
    {
        if (server == null) throw new Exception("please send a server");

        this.objServer = server;
    }

    string WeatherReport()
    {
        return objServer.City + " " + objServer.temprature);
    }
}
```

during testing you can do this

```
class UnitTest
{
    void Should_Return_NewYork_20DegreeBelowZero()
    {
        WeatherReportDisplay obj = new WeatherReportDisplay(new MockServer);
        var result = obj.PrintWeatherReport  ();
        Assert.IsEqual(result, "NewYork_20DegreeBelowZero");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... But we found implementing jmetter on regular basis. it helps us on unit testing along with performance testing.